# Subversion with Apache and permissions issues

Tags: linux, svn, apache, permissions, chmod

I have setup an SVN repository for use with Apache 2 via `svnadmin create` command and appropriate vhost configuration. I found that, in order to correctly use the repository, this must be owned by `wwwrun` user (or `www` group) or chmodded to `777`.

I would like to ask if it's possible to explicitly tell Apache to impersonate another user when serving requests to a certain path (from vhost.conf), *like with `suphp` extension*, so I won't mess with permissions once I create a repository.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To impersonate another user, apache would need to have elevated privileges - this would miss the point of running apache with limited rights (as use `wwwrun` in your example) in the first place. Therefore, pick one of the following

- Run apache as root (dangerous, since a compromised apache will compromise your entire system)
- Make `wwwrun` member of the `svnrepo` group that you give access to your repository to
- Create a `suid` binary and a corresponding apache module to allow apache to impersonate (very complicated, easy to mess up - that's how suphp does it)
- Change the permissions of the repository itself to allow everybody, `wwwrun`, or the `www` group.

Quite frankly, I don't see the problem you're having with the second or last option. Why can't you allow `wwwrun` to access your svn repository?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I asked this question because the second option (my favourite) could be tricky for users with no root access on the server if they mess up the repository (they will have to call the admin and fix the privileges). My question was oriented for shared-hosting environments, but I didn't highlight that. Surely is a good way, but if users make a private repository and somebody with another account on the server manages to get the path of the repo, he can create a PHP script that fetches the private repository via svnadmin dump. If you say suid is difficult, I believe you